# $p$-state Potts Model and symmetry

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, hamiltonian, spin-models

Consider a lattice spin system where the spin variable is the $i$th site
can have $p$ values, 0, 1, . . . , p − 1, and the nearest-neighbor Hamiltonian describes the system

[image: Potts Model Hamiltonian]

This is called a $p$-state Potts model.
What symmetry transformation keeps the Hamiltonian of the $p$-state Potts model invariant?

Comment: Any permutation of the $p$ possible spin states preserves the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Could you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: I wrote a short answer, as explaining in comments is too annoying...

Answer (score 4):

Any **permutation** of the $p$ possible spin states preserves the Hamiltonian.

Consider an arbitrary configuration $(\sigma_i)_{i\in V}$ of $p$-Potts spins. Let $A_s = \{i\in V\,:\,\sigma_i = s\}$ be the set of all spins taking value $s$. Now, if you set the value of all spins in $A_0$ to, say, $1$ and the value of all spins in $A_1$ to $0$, then the energy of the resulting configuration is still the same, since the only thing that matters is whether two spins take the same value or not, not the specific values involved.

More generally, if $\pi$ is a permutation of the set $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$, and you define the configuration $\sigma'$ by
$$
\sigma'_i = \pi(\sigma_i)
$$
(which amounts to interchanging the state $s$ by the state $\pi(s)$ for all $s\in\{0,\dots,p-1\}$),
then $H(\sigma')=H(\sigma)$.

In the particular case $p=2$, which coincides with the Ising model, there is a single nontrivial permutation: $\pi(0)=1$, $\pi(1)=0$. Acting with $\pi$ corresponds to flipping all the Ising spins and you recover the spin-flip invariance of the Ising Hamiltonian.